# Reading Linksys EA3500 Configuration File

Tags: router, backup, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

Is there a way to view the configuration of a Linksys EA3500 from a .cfg backup of the router's configuration? What I mean is, can I open the backup file to view the configuration settings of the router?

Comment: To state the obvious - have you tried a text editor?

Comment: Yes, I have. Garbled, unreadable text shows up so I believe I'd perhaps need a Linksys application that's capable of allowing me to read the file. Possibly the Linksys Connect Setup Software, but I'm having trouble getting it run on my MacBook.